# Tomcat in eclipse gives timeout if Log4j is not with priority debug

Tags: eclipse, log4j, tomcat7, java-7

Yesterday all at once I started to get timeout problems with my tomcat in eclipse. I hadn't changed anything and my colleges do not have the same issues.

I changed the priority in log4j from error to debug and strangly enough by doing this tomcat doesn't go into a timeout and runs fine. Immediatly when I change the priority back to error (or warn, info, fatal) and startup tomcat I get a timeout.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be? I tried everything. Switching to java 7 (instead of 8 on windows), reinstalling tomcat, installing a new eclipse (now Mars, had Luna before), deleting the server and creating it again,...

But only changing the priority to debug in log4j seems to work!?

This slows down the loading of the site so I would like to put it back to error.

Anyone had a similar problem and got a fix?

Comment: Do you use [isDebugEnabled](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#isDebugEnabled%28%29) in if-statements in your code? Maybe you have some code that prevents the timeout in such a statement?

Comment: no, I really can't imagine why this happens